# How to keep object with pattern in list?

Tags: python

```
L1=['241212','21441','2431212'.....]
```

I want to create L2 from L1.
L2 only contain those string with substring `'1212'`.

Here is my code, and I don't know what's wrong with it?

```
x=["111241","2131231","111123432"]
[a if "1111" in a for a in x]
```

Comment: juste reverse the expressions `[a for a in x if "1111" in a ]`

Comment: How can I apply this to dataframe? I simply do this `df['S2']=df['S1'].apply(lambda x:[a] for a in x if ":1111:" in a )`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Problem 2 has been solved by `df['S2']=df['S1'].apply(lambda x:[a for a in x if ":1111:" in a] )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

You should write list comprehensions like this:

```
[a for a in x if "1111" in a]
```

Comment: Thx! May I ask an additional question? How can I apply this to df ? I simply do this `df['S2']=df['S1'].apply(lambda x:[a] for a in x if ":1111:" in a )`, but it didn't work.

Comment: OH! I have solved by `df['S2']=df['S1'].apply(lambda x:[a for a in x if ":1111:" in a] )`